# Turn the border color into the background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a parent div with a background color. And inside that I've got a ul with lots of li's, each with a different color and each with a brighter border color. Now I want to copy the border color of the li, and use that as background for the parent div.

```
<div class="content">
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="item"></li>
        <li class="item"></li>
        <li class="item"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I found this JQuery code, which copies the background color. It works, but I want the border color.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li.item").click(function(){
        var bg = ['background-color',];
        var $this = $(this);
        $.each(bg , function(item, value) {
            $("div.macbook-content").css(value, $this.css(value));
        });
    });
});
```

Does anybody know what to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you didn't attach your css I made up my own, try out the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jg51h5c5/

Here's the jQuery changes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("li.item").click(function(){
    var bg = $(this).css("border-top-color");
    $("div.content").css("background-color",bg);
  });
});
```

**updated to work in Firefox**
The key to working in Firefox is you must define which part of the border you want: top, bottom, left, right

Comment: Sorry, my CSS is quite big I couldn't find the right elements. Your JSFiddle doesn't seem to work, and when I tried to copy your code into my website it didn't work either.

Comment: @VascovanderEng are you using Firefox?

Comment: @JosanIracheta Yes. And after you've said that I tried using it in google chrome and it does work there! Thank you. But why doesn't it work on firefox and how do I make it work?

Comment: @VascovanderEng I have no idea but I was having the same problems too with FIrefox.

Comment: What browser are you using?  Is your javascript turned on in the browser?  My fiddle and the one below me that you also said doesn't work absolutely works.  Just to clarify your expecting them to click the li and the background color changes to the li's border color?

Comment: Ah, I'm using Chrome as well.  I will test it in Firefox

Comment: I'm using Firefox because of an awesome extension called 'Firebug'. And yes, what I want is when a user clicks on a li, the li's border color becomes the background color the the div that the li's are in.

Comment: ok, this is apparently a well know Firefox bug, here's the fix http://jsfiddle.net/jg51h5c5/

Comment: I have also updated my answer above to be compatible with Firefox

Comment: Another user suggested to use "border-left-color", but yours works too. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can actually use: top, bottom, left, or right.  It doesn't matter as long as which side is defined

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `border color` just like you are getting the `background color`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li.item").click(function(){
        var bg = ['border-left-color'];
        var currentItem = $(this);
        $.each(bg , function(item, value) {
            $("div.macbook-content").css('background-color', currentItem.css(value));
        });
    });
});
```

This should work fine: [JSFiddle Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/bardhlohaj/dS7mc/57/)

Comment: I've tried something like that as well. And even that could work, it would not show up because "var bg" is a array of attributes of the <li>. So it would give the content a border color.

Comment: You don't need to set all the attributes of the `li` to the `parent` element. You can set directly the `background-color` from the `border-color`. I added a `JSFiddle` example.

Comment: I know, I got that code from another post. I was happy that it worked. And I'm sorry but your JSFiddle doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It works, if you click on the first rect, it will pass the color to the background color of the second rect.

Comment: It seems that this method doesn't work in Firefox, it does in Chrome. Other people have answered the same method.

Comment: try to use `border-left-color` instead of `border-color` than.

Comment: What that actually woked? How?!?! Thank you so much!

Comment: As it seems, other browser don't accept using shorthand for jQuery and `border-color` is a shorthand.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vwq5gL7/5/) I just made. It sets the parent's backgound colour as the list item's border when clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("li.item").click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.parents('div.content')
            .css('background', $this.css('border-color'));
   });
});
```

Comment: So weird, it wouldn't work on Firefox but it works on Chrome. Is it just me?

Answer (score 0):

run this

## html

```
<div class="content">
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="item">1</li>
        <li class="item">2</li>
        <li class="item">3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class='chk'>5</div>
```

## css

```
.content {
    background:red;
}
li.item {
    border: 1px solid #666;
    background:green;
}
.chk{
    background:blue;
}
```

## jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li.item").click(function () {
        var bg = ['border-top-color', ];
        var $this = $(this);
        $.each(bg, function (item, value) {
            $("div.chk").css('background-color', $this.css(value));
        });
    });
});
```